Finding height of triangle DEH: Alternative to intersection method using similar triangles?
I solved this geometry problem (see the image below) involving a rectangle $ABCD$ with area $300$ square units. Point $F$ is the midpoint of $AB$, and points $E$ and $G$ divide $DC$ into thirds. I need to find the area of $\triangle DEH$ (shaded in purple).

I found the height of $\triangle DEH$ using the intersection of lines:

I set up line $DB$: $$y = \frac{w}{l}x$$
Line $EF$: $$y = \frac{6w}{l}\left(x - \frac{l}{3}\right)$$
Found their intersection point at $$\left(\frac{2l}{5}, \frac{2w}{5}\right)$$
This gave me the height $$\frac{2w}{5}$$ for $\triangle DEH$

My teacher mentioned there's a simpler way using similar triangles, but I'm not sure how to approach it. I can see that triangles $DEH$ and $DFB$ might be similar, but I'm stuck on how to use this to find the height without using intersections.
Can someone help explain how to solve this using similar triangles? What properties should I focus on?
Note: My answer is the final area comes to $20$ square units.
Citations:
1 https://pplx-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/v1735448481/user_uploads/ilZOinIWkYjtVcY/8d5d6fd2-0abb-4056-b027-01c01bdf3bcd.jpg


In what follows, we denote the area of $\Delta XYZ$ by $[XYZ]$.
Note that $\Delta HDE \sim \Delta HBF$
$\therefore  DE:FB=2:3 \implies DH:HB=2:3$
This implies that $[HDE]:[HBE]=HD:HB=2:3$.
Let $[HDE]=S$, then $[HBE]=\frac{3S}{2}$ and hence $[BDE]=\frac{5S}{2}$.
Finally note that $[BDE]=\frac{[BCD]}{3}=\frac{[ABCD]}{6}$.
Therefore we have $$\frac{5S}{2}=\frac{300}{6}$$
$$S=20$$
$$[HDE]=20$$

Thank you so much!
